# SonarQube/VSTS - Project specific exclusions

Tags: sonarqube, azure-pipelines-build-task

My current setup is running on SQ v6.5 and SonarC# 6.4.1

I have multiple projects which have interdependence on other projects, worked on by different owners (teams). I am trying to setup a build for each team that will only show files specific to that team. To achieve that I tried to setup as below via UI for the specific project (Project > Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope).

ProjectKey - Team_A

Project Exclusions - sonar.exclusions = **/* Team_B */ ** (without spaces).

As the source structure is root/workspace/Team_{id}/TeamSpecificCode, I believed putting the wildcard like above would ignore Team B's code while doing analysis.

1. When the analysis finished on the dashboard I could still see the issues listed from Team_B and its sub-directories.
2. Even though I added this via UI, to a specific project, I can still view these when I view global settings or settings of Team_B project.

I wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong. I am running these via VSTS build tasks so I believe it should honor the server settings. There are no additional settings mentioned at the moment (and if I can set it via UI I would prefer to avoid setting additional settings)

**Additional Info:** 
I have already tried in VSTS additional settings as well. This causes issue with multiple settings in it. I tried that with comma and semi colon but the task breaks due to unknown commands. eg./d:sonar.exclusions=** /* Team_B */ **, ** /* Team_C */ **

Outcome though is the same either via additional tasks or server side setup. The marked directories are not excluded from analysis.

Comment: Have you considered sharing cross-team dependencies as NuGet packages? Having unversioned cross-team source code dependencies seems like a nightmare to manage.

Comment: Agreed. This is in my pipeline, but honestly I can't see that happening any time soon due to various issues including time, as most of this dependency is shared legacy code built over few years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `sonar.exclusions` in Additional Settings of **Prepare the SonarQube analysis** task:

`/d:sonar.exclusions=**/*Team_B*/**`

Comment: I have already tried this. This doesn't seem to have any effect. Also I had issues getting multiple settings in it. I tried that with comma and semi colon but the task breaks due to unknown commands while applying exclusions as it seems to detect the second exclusion as a separate command. eg./d:sonar.exclusions=**/*Team_B*/**, ** /*Team_C*/ **

Comment: Does the task version is 3.*? Set system.debug to true and queue build, then share the detail log on the OneDrive.

Comment: Unrecognized command line argument: ** /*Team_C*/ **

This is the error i get when i have added exclusions as above.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (It works fine for me)

Comment: Seems like it was an issue with this version. After upgrading the SQ version same exclusions were applied correctly.